# How to get first and last document in collection?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have [google-cloud-firestore](/questions/tagged/google-cloud-firestore) collection with many documents.
I want to get first and last document in collection (sorted by timestamp).

How can I query for this?

Comment: Firestore doesn't do timestamp ordering of documents by default.  You have to add a timestamp field to each document, and use that in your queries.  You will need at least two queries to get only these two documents.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure by which `Timestamp` you want to sort, so I'm gonna assume your `doc` looks something like this
>
> ```json
> /id/: {
>  timestamp: FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp
>  // ... whatever other properties
> }
> ```

You can get a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query) by querying on a `CollectionReference<T>` via the [`.orderBy`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#orderby) method.

```js
const collectionQuery = firestore
  .collection('collectionName')
  .orderBy('timestamp', 'asc')
```

Now we want to get a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) *(which will allow us to access the documents)*, by using the [`.get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#get) method.

```js
const collectionSnapshot = await collectionQuery.get()
```

Now we just access the first and the last document.

```js
const firstDocument = collectionSnapshot.isEmpty
 ? null
 : collectionSnapshot.docs[0]
const lastDocument = collectionSnapshot.isEmpty
 ? null
 : collectionSnapshot.docs[collectionSnapshot.docs.length - 1]
```

And voila, you have your first and last document! :-)

Comment: first, and last - and downloading every document in between.  A rather expensive operation. The other answer queries *only* the two documents, and incurs the *read* cost of only two documents.

Comment: @LeadDreamer actually I'd be curious what's more performance heavy, accessing the docs or the two asynchronous calls on the two separate `orderBy` queries, though they have limit so I'd assume they are more performant. I'd be curious if internally the `limit` actually does something to the `CollectionReference` or just fetches and then then simply returns the first `QueryDocument`

Comment: limit(1) **literally** only fetches one document, so costs 1 read.  It only transports one document, so less bandwidth used. It only transports one document so it takes less time.  All at the server.  *IF*, for some reason, you were to *subsequently* *always* need the rest of the documents, then they would then be in cache, but I don't see a *performance* reason **NOT** to use .limit()